# To call dispatch function in react

Tags: reactjs, dispatch

I don't know where to call dispatch(setAlert()) function. I want it after axios.patch request but currently it's not working

```
  let url = `.....................`;
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    axios
      .patch(url, form_data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      dispatch(setAlert('Data changed successfully.', 'success'));
      .then(() => axios.get(url))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        updateFormData({
          ...formData
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
```

Comment: it must be in then block, above or below `updateFormData ` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `dispatch` call within `then` right after `patch` call:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    axios
      .patch(url, form_data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
         dispatch(setAlert('Data changed successfully.', 'success'));
         axios.get(url));
       }
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        updateFormData({
          ...formData
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
```

**EDIT**:
Make sure you either connect the component in case of class component or import `useDispatch` hook in case of functional component, like:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

function SomeComponent() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    ...
    // your code place

}
```

Comment: Are you placing this code within the component that is connected with redux and getting `dispatch` from the props?

Comment: What redux version you are using?

Comment: "react-redux": "^7.2.1",  "redux": "^4.0.5",

Comment: Updated the answer to use `dispatch`

Comment: This worked ..Thank you for your time and answer really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

You can use async / wait and then wait till the patch call is done.

```js
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    await axios
      .patch(url, form_data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      dispatch(setAlert('Data changed successfully.', 'success'));
      .then(() => axios.get(url))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        updateFormData({
          ...formData
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
```